# Adding values from icalendar to variables from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called event which attributes are:

```
string "name"
string "location"
string "lecturer"
date "start_time"
date "end_time"`
```

How do I assign data from icalendar file into my variables ? I tried something like this

```
@ievent_file = File.open("calendar2.ics")
@ievents = Icalendar::Event.parse(@ievent_file)
@ievent = @ievents.first
@event = Event.new(@ievent)
```

But it shows that I need hash instead of variable `@ievent`. Also that's a bit stupid because there are more variables in icalendar event, but earlier I tried to assign singly variables like `Event.new(@ievent.summary,@ievent.location, @ievent.description, @ievent.dtstart, @ievent.dtend)` but it also showed me that I need hash. So how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hash like:

```
Event.new(name:@ievent.summary,location:@ievent.location, lecturer:@ievent.description, start_time:@ievent.dtstart, end_time:@ievent.dtend)
```